# iOS - Zoom into pdf in webview after it has loaded

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiwebview

I have the following code, which loads a pdf from the apps documents into a `UIWebView`.

```
-(IBAction)viewMyPdf:(id)sender {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myfilename.pdf"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webView loadRequest:request];
    [webView setScalesPageToFit:YES];

    [self performSelector:@selector(theTest) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0];
}

-(void)theTest {
    NSLog(@"Hello");
    [webView.scrollView setZoomScale:5.0 animated:NO];
    webView.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(480, 360);
}
```

As you can see, at the end I am calling `theTest` to zoom into and set an appropriate position to start with (As I don't want to begin with the pdf fitting to the page). This has a delay of 0.2 which is undesirable because the time delay can vary and so the zoom effect may not happen (if load takes longer than 0.2s) or it feels very buggy and jumpy (depending on how much sooner it loads, than the 0.2 delay).

Is there a robust way to zoom in and position my pdf once it is loaded into the `UIWebView`?

**EDIT:** `-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {` does not seem to help either. It prints the NSLog but the zoom does not work. The webview does have its delegate set accordingly.

Comment: [webView setScalesPageToFit:NO] is not good enough?

Comment: @Till Nope, that disables scrolling and loads pdf to fit to page anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you try the `QuickLook` framework, if I understood well your question could do exactly what you are looking for. See that [tutorial](http://iphonebyradix.blogspot.it/2012/02/load-pdf-file-in-iphone-app-smoothly.html)